# Unable to perform basic arithmetic

Tags: f#

In F#, I receive an error when I write the following code:

```
let records = {1..100}
let middleElement= records |> Seq.length / 2
```

> The type 'int' does not match the type ''a -> int'

I know this error is basic.
But I'm new to F# and really don't know what I need to do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add parentheses:

```
let middleElement = (records |> Seq.length) / 2
```

In your version, the compiler reads your code as

```
let middleElement = records |> (Seq.length / 2)
```

... and it gets confused, because it thinks you are trying to divide the `length` function by 2!

Answer (score 1):

I endorse Tomas Petricek's answer, but you could also write it this way. :-)

```
let records = {1..100}
let middleElement = records |> Seq.length |> (/) <| 2
```

This says, take the records, feed them to the length function. Feed the result as the first argument to the divide (/) function. This will result in a function which takes an int and returns an int (int -> int). We then feed 2 to that function to get 50.

[Edit] I just realized that this might be even clearer

```
let records = {1..100}
let middleElement = let length = records |> Seq.length in length / 2;;
```